# Is there a possibility to make the `\ref` command return `\part` numbers in addition to `chapter`, `section` and `subsection` numbering?

Tags: cross-referencing

As a default documentclass `book` numbers chapters consecutively regardless of the division into parts, and I suppose the `\ref` command had been designed with this in mind, returning as it does `chapter`, `section` and `subsection` numbering. The clause `\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}` will cause chapters to be numbered starting with 1 for each part. Is there a way of paramatrizing `\ref` to return `part` numbers?

```
\documentclass{book}
% RN. 10 Nov 2018
%=======================
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter*{Preface}
Referencing both sections produce identical numbering. It would be helpful to distinguish parts:\\
\ref{A1}, page \pageref{A1}\\
\ref{B1}, page \pageref{B1}\\
\part{FIRST}
\chapter{A}
\section{A1}\label{A1}
\part{SECOND}
\chapter{B}
\section{B1}\label{B1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Something like `\renewcommand*{\p@section}{\thepart.}` (within `\makeatletter...\makeatother`)?

Comment: Works like a charm. How do I mark this as the answer?

Comment: You need to ping @moewe and ask that the text be re-posted as an answer, you can't mark comments as accepted answers.

Comment: To complete @moewe 's answer I now use `\renewcommand*{\p@chapter}{\thepart.}`, `\renewcommand*{\p@section}{\thepart.}` and `\renewcommand*{\p@subsection}{\thepart.}`, sandwiched beween `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, and have `\ref` return numbering for all `part/chapter/section/subsection' as required. 
Please repost your comment as an answer so I can tick it off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can redefine `\p@<counter>` to modify the output of `\ref` without changing the actual representation of `<counter>` elsewhere. You might try something like `\renewcommand*{\p@section}{\thepart.}` or similar.

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\renewcommand*{\p@chapter}{\thepart.}
\renewcommand*{\p@section}{\thepart.}
\renewcommand*{\p@subsection}{\thepart.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Preface}
Referencing both sections produce identical numbering. It would be helpful to distinguish parts:

\ref{A1}, page \pageref{A1}

\ref{B1}, page \pageref{B1}

\part{FIRST}
\chapter{A}
\section{A1}\label{A1}

\part{SECOND}
\chapter{B}
\section{B1}\label{B1}
\end{document}
```

[image: the <code>\ref</code>s produce "I.1.1, page 5" and "II.1.1, page 9"]